# What is a 'reminder' in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice-writer

In LibreOffice Writer, in the "Navigator" sidebar, if I click on the 'Navigation' compass icon (see image) one of the things is a "Reminder". What is the reminder that this refers to, and how would I insert one?

[image: The buttons I clicked on, from the right (first) to left.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The
[LibreOffice Writer 6.0 Guide](https://documentation.libreoffice.org/assets/Uploads/Documentation/en/WG6.0/WG60-WriterGuideLO.pdf)
says this:

> **Setting reminders**
>
> Reminders let you mark places in your document that you want to return
>   to later on, for example to add or correct information or simply mark
>   where you finished editing. The possible uses of reminders are limited
>   only by your imagination.
>
> To set a reminder at the cursor’s current location, click the Set
>   Reminder icon in the Navigator. You can set up to 5 reminders in a
>   document; setting a sixth causes the first to be deleted.
>
> Reminders are not highlighted in any way in the document, nor are they
>   listed in the Navigator, so you cannot see where they are, except that
>   when you jump from one to the next, the location of the cursor shows
>   the location of the reminder.
>
> To jump between reminders, first select the Reminder icon on the
>   Navigation toolbar. Then click the Previous and Next icons. Reminders
>   are not saved with the document